# Error compiling Xcode 9 project: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_mptcp_go"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, xcode9

I have a problem when trying to build Xcode 9 app. It shows two errors:

```
1: "_mptcp_go", referenced from:
      ___36-[ViewController tappedOnJailbreak:]_block_invoke in ViewController.old: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
2: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix it? (by the way, tried running workspace and .xcodeproj, but none of them worked)

Here is full code of errors:

```
Ld /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Undecimus.app/Undecimus normal arm64
    cd "/Users/mac/Desktop/SNIRL JB/Undecimus-master"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk -L/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/mac/Desktop/SNIRL\ JB/Undecimus-master/Undecimus -F/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/mac/Desktop/SNIRL\ JB/Undecimus-master/Undecimus -filelist /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Undecimus.build/Debug-iphoneos/Undecimus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Undecimus.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=11.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Undecimus.build/Debug-iphoneos/Undecimus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Undecimus_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework IOKit -lMobileGestalt -ljb /Users/mac/Desktop/SNIRL\ JB/Undecimus-master/Undecimus/qilin.o -framework SpringBoardServices -lPods-Undecimus -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Undecimus.build/Debug-iphoneos/Undecimus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Undecimus_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Undecimus-alrztlqurpvdagfnhitjmaasoboy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Undecimus.app/Undecimus

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_mptcp_go", referenced from:
      ___36-[ViewController tappedOnJailbreak:]_block_invoke in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

GitHub link to a project - https://github.com/Horunu/stuffy

Comment: What app are you building? Can reduce your code to a little sample that still has your problem, and then share the code with us in your question?

Comment: Do I need to share a project or what?

Comment: @NOLOKIPC yes, you need to share a [MCVE]: either a piece of code, or a Podfile/Cartfile/Gemfile, or a project, but something that can let others reproduce the same error message.

Comment: @Cœur GitHub link do a project - https://github.com/Horunu/stuffy

Comment: @Cœur thank you, but how do i fix it (tried finding solution for 14 hours)

Comment: You seem to have the same code as https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/saigon. One of the errors at build time is: .../stuffy/Undecimus/QiLin.h:242:27: Unknown type name '_STRUCT_ARM_THREAD_STATE64'

Comment: Regarding the specific error related to `_mptcp_go`, it's because you didn't include  `multi_path_sploit.h` and `multi_path_sploit.c` in your project target. So, right click, add files, and add the two missing files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjiSK.png